# How to get reviewer's name from status change object of a workflow transition?

Tags: python, workflow, plone

How can I get the details of users for whom the state is intended?

In my case I have a 4-state workflow with private as initial state, then pending, reviewed and published. When a contributor adds a page its state is private and he can request for review. The reviewer then gets a notification email on the transition (I have added a Python script to send the mail).

Since Products.DCWorkflow has 5 default variables (action, actor, time, comments and review_history), I'm able to get the user who has requested the transition by using the actor variable:

```
actorid = wf_tool.getInfoFor(obj, 'actor')  
actor = context.portal_membership.getMemberById(actorid)
```

My problem is: how to get the details of the user who *is going to* review?

PS: my script works on status_change object of workflow.

Answer (score 5):

You *can't* get the name of the person who "is going to review" - it's not fixed until someone reviews.  In a default setup, you could find the list of members of the Reviewers group through the Groups tool, and know who is *authorized* to review, but that's not the same thing.